# ASP.NET controls and HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

Why do built-in ASP.NET controls generate HTML that VS2010 tells me is not HTML5 compatible? Is there a way around it?

Example: Drop a `PasswordRecovery` control onto your page and ask it to convert the UserName (or Question or Answer) view into a template. The generated HTML contains attributes like `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` and VS2010 underlines them with the warning: *Attribute 'cellspacing' is not a valid attribute of element 'table'*.

N.B. You have to set Target Schema to HTML5 to see these warnings.

Comment: coz **CELLPADDING** and **CELLSPACING** is obsolute in HTML5.., you can use CSS to use that controls..

Comment: @GopeshSharma: Thanks, but that is not what I'm asking. Of course I  understand that these attributes are deprecated in HTML5. The question is, why does VS2010 generate these attribs even when Target Schema is set to HTML5 and is there a way to force it to generate HTML5 compatible code?

Comment: are you using **XHTML 1.0** transitional opening incantation?, bdw have you install Web Standards Update?

Comment: @GopeshSharma: I'm not too sure what that is (being relatively new to ASP.NET). I do see **XHTML 1.0 Transactional** in the list of Target Schemas, but that is not what I'm using. As I said, I have set it to HTML5. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @Aristos: Wow. I had a hard time making sense out of that, but I guess I understand what you're saying. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @dotNET To say it with other words. The VS have only one template that renders. Can not change it base on the html5. This attributes for me is not so bad to have them, and you only get warning to use css.

Comment: @Aristos: Correct. But you see when you have soooo many of these "false" warnings, those "real" warnings get burried somewhere in that long list and you never know.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should install [Web Standards Update](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingTheWebStandardsUpdateHTML5SupportForTheVisualStudio2010Editor.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20ScottHanselman%20%28Scott%20Hanselman%20-%20ComputerZen.com%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)
And then change the XHTML 1.0 transitional opening incantation to HTML 5 i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Comment: That sounds interesting. I'll take a look.